# python pip install calling module by name in terminal

Tags: python, shell, path, pip, shebang

I've noticed that for some packages, for example, `ipython` and `termdown`, after I've successfully installed them with `pip install`, they can be immediately invoked from the terminal. e.g:

```
$ termdown 100
```

I understand that the primary file within these packages are operated by the `#!` shebang line and hence callable, however, where in the python directory are the hook that allowed them to become callable stored? e.g. a `/bin` folder where everything can be invoked from the terminal? Or is there some other mechanism like `PATH` in play? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when a `Python` package is installed via `pip`, `setuptools`, etc. two mechanisms can be invoked within the packages `setup.py` file to produce a CLI executable command:

The **`scripts`** keyword argument and the **`console_scripts`** entry point.

Usually a symlink is created within `/usr/local/bin` that points back to the installed package.

↳ [Python Packaging | Command Line Scripts](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html)